# How to access a SQL Server corporate database remotely?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I am a new web developer and in my company they put the web application in one of the servers and the database in another server which is located in the company data center.

Now, there is a problem in one of the ASP.NET applications which is basically about giving one of the users the whole admin right on that system. That system lacks the feature of adding users and giving them this role. So basically I have to access that corporate database and go the UserRoles table and give the user the desired role. So how to do that?

From the web config file, I could be able to know the name and location of the database. The database is SQL Server. And I want now to access it remotely if it is possible. So how to do that?

Comment: With any luck, your company's servers are secure enough that you *can't* access them directly :)  Talk to your company's IT department to see what kind of access they arrange for you to have.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SQL Server Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8961) or [SSMSE 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/betaexperience/pd/SQLEXPCTAV2/enus/default.aspx) which is the latest edition to connect to remote Sql Server databases, and run queries.

Answer (score 0):

You should see what are deploying practices in your organization and follow it, probably that includes :

1. You writing the update SQL script
2. Contacting DB admin to deploy that script on production server